# Why Laravel email validation accepting emojis? is it a larvel bug/issue?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Why a wrong email is accepted even after using laravel validator?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [            
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return ResponseBuilder::error($validator->errors()->first(), '422');
        }
```

This set of code accepts  "@ot.com". I don't think this should be accepted.

Comment: Just checked within tinker and such validation passes. 
`\Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(['email' => ' @ot.co'], ['email' => 'required|email'])->passes()`

You may discuss it right within laravel framework repo:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/categories/general